# Connecting a remote Mysql database to a Wordpress website

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a 40MB Mysql database with all my products in it.
I use that database to manage my products as I sell those products on several platform/marketplaces.
I created a new website in Wordpress and was wondering if I could link that database to my new website (instead of the wordpress database), allowing me to use only 1 database for everything.
Any idea if this is feasible?
I am new to wordpress and a little bit confused as to how to do this.

Comment: accessing the database remotely is possible but using it as is from wordpress is not straightforward as wordrpress uses a specific database schema. I guess you have a product catalog in your database as you are referring to woocomerce. If you want to use your own database as a data source in wordpress, you'll have to develop a connector plugin to extract your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do that. You can use any database sitting anywhere for your Wordpress installation. Note that allowing remote connections opens you up to security issues so you want to make sure your Wordpress to database traffic is secure (encrypted) and password-protected.

This [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html) contains more information about how you configure MySQL to allow remote connections.

Comment: Thaknk you David. That is what I thought. Could you please guide me on how to do this?

Comment: Just added a link with more info